# HDF5: Do I need to to explicitly set the byte order?

Tags: c++, hdf5

In some of the HDF5 examples in the manual of the HDF5 group the byte order is explicitly set to 'little endian'. In some other examples no explicit definition is given. My question is now, do I need to care about the byte order? Can I simply not specify it, and rely on the default?

A snippet from an [example in which the byte order is explicitly specified](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/create_8cpp-example.html):

```
DataSpace dataspace( RANK, dimsf );

IntType datatype( PredType::NATIVE_INT );
datatype.setOrder( H5T_ORDER_LE );

DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet( DATASET_NAME, datatype, dataspace );
```

What if I just use the following?

```
DataSpace dataspace( RANK, dimsf );

DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet( DATASET_NAME, PredType::NATIVE_INT, dataspace );
```

(I have verified that both compile and run, and give the same data if I read with HDFView and h5py)

Comment: You probably will not notice any difference as long as you are on a little endian architecture. Intels x86 (and x64) are little endian (always AFAIK). However, there are big endian architectures in use and other allow even switching... I remember that [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) supports little and big endian. You have to consider this when reading or writing raw data as endianess of file need not to match endianess of CPU/architecture and hence swapping may be required. An API function (which is compiled _for_ your specific architecture) may consider this "under the hood".

Comment: @Scheff That is clear, thank you. Do you know if the HDF5 API takes care of this?

Comment: Hence, I would guess the following. There is a certain default for the endianess of files which is either always the same or always platform-dependent (as native endianess I/O is probably faster). If not changed the default is used when writing. For reading, it should be retrieved from file itself to convert file endianess to architecture endianess.

Comment: Sorry, all I know about HDF5 I know because I stumbled over this in SO and then googled a bit. Because there was no other attention, I thought it could be worth to share my general understanding (as it should be in HDF5 as it is in any other file format which supports switching of endianess).

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed your question if I hadn't recognized the "bite" while scanning the questions. I couldn't live with this but felt a little bit poor only to fix these little typos...

Comment: @Scheff Thanks! So in principle, if I make an explicit choice it should probably be such that it matches the platform on which I will do most of the reading, to have the most efficiency? For the rest, maybe somebody with more knowledge about HDF5 will contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing and reading data, the HDF5 library considers two datatypes, the one in memory on the one on disk.

Consider, for instance, the doc of [H5Dread](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Read):

> The memory datatype of the (partial) dataset is identified by the
>   identifier mem_type_id.
>   (...)
>   Datatype conversion takes place at the time of a read or write and is automatic.

The datatype "on disk" will be inferred from the metadata of the dataset. This is also explained in the user guide, see [The Data Transfer Pipeline](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/HDF5_Users_Guide/LibraryAndProgrammingModel/The_HDF5_Library_and_Programming_Model.htm?rhtocid=2.1_1#TOC_2_3_The_Data_Transferbc-13) (where the relevant part is "transform" in the diagram) and [Data Transfer: Datatype Conversion and Selection](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/index.html#t=HDF5_Users_Guide%2FDatatypes%2FHDF5_Datatypes.htm%23TOC_6_10_Data_Transferbc-26&rhtocid=6.5_2) for the details.

So, when reading data, you don't need to care about what's "on disk", it will be handled (including endianness) by HDF5.

Another transformation will happen if you store 64-bit floats into a 32-bit float dataset, on the fly when calling H5Dwrite.

When writing data, you can either choose the native type provided by HDF5 or another one if you have constraints on the storage type. I use HDF5 since years from C, Fortran and Python and never had to worry about any of this. (Well, after a long period of getting to grasp the several concepts in HDF5).

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! Also, via the C++ API manual I had not reached these pages. I guess that I was a bit confused by the examples there, as for example [this reading example](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/readdata_8cpp-example.html) starts with a lot of checking. But I infer from you that I can skip most of it as the API will 'shield' me. (I have had more confusion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110290/read-with-exactly-the-right-type-or-does-the-api-take-care-of-conversions).)

Comment: I don't use C++ with HDF5 myself but even when using Fortran or Python I have a look at the documentation of the C API as all others depend on it. For reading, the API will decode the dataset as needed, including decompression.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definitive answer but I found it worth to share it (and it's too much for a comment):

From HDF5 User's Guide [Chapter 6 HDF5 Datatypes](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/11_Datatypes.html):

> **2.3 Data transfer (Read and Write)**
>
> Probably the most common use of datatypes is to write or read data from a dataset or attribute. In these operations, each data element is transferred from the source to the destination (possibly rearranging the order of the elements). Since the source and destination do not need to be identical (i.e., one is disk and the other is memory) the transfer requires both the format of the source element and the destination element. Therefore, data transfers use two datatype objects, for the source and destination.
>
> When data is written, the source is memory and the destination is disk (file). The memory datatype describes the format of the data element in the machine memory, and the file datatype describes the desired format of the data element on disk. Similarly, when reading, the source datatype describes the format of the data element on disk, and the destination datatype describes the format in memory.
>
> In the most common cases, the file datatype is the datatype specified when the dataset was created, and the memory datatype should be the appropriate NATIVE type.

This doesn't contradict with what has been told in the comments before...

Comment: @TomdeGeus To be honest, this part of manual doesn't clarify the things fully for me. 1st. your conclusion in your last comment (the one I voted up) sounds very reasonable to me. 2nd. If I were in your place, I would make a minimal sample and do experiments e.g. with an `int` containing `0x11223344`. If you can force the HDF5 API to return values in a non-native endianess (for whatever this might be good for) this could be a possible source for decoding errors and something you should care about in productive work...